# window.matchMedia is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, graphql, gatsby

I have some problem with `window` global object on build project in gatsby. I use custom media hook for change login in some resolutions. It's work fine when project running. But when i try `npm run build` for build project  Webpack gives error : **WebpackError: TypeError: window.matchMedia is not a function**

```
  const useMedia = (query) => {
    const windowGlobal = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window
    const [matches, setMatches] = useState(windowGlobal.matchMedia(query).matches)
    useEffect(() => {
      const media = windowGlobal.matchMedia(query)
      if (media.matches !== matches) setMatches(media.matches)
      const listener = () => setMatches(media.matches)
      media.addEventListener('change', listener)
      return () => media.removeEventListener('change', listener)
    }, [matches, query])

    return matches
  }
  const match = useMedia('(max-width: 575px)')
  const changeLabel = match ? 'Cancel' : 'Add Now'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 const useMedia = (query) => {
    const [matches, setMatches] = useState(typeof window !=='undefined' && window.matchMedia(query).matches);

    useEffect(() => {
      const media = windowGlobal.matchMedia(query)
      if (media.matches !== matches) setMatches(media.matches)
      const listener = () => setMatches(media.matches)
      media.addEventListener('change', listener)
      return () => media.removeEventListener('change', listener)
    }, [matches, query])

    return matches
  }
  const match = useMedia('(max-width: 575px)')
  const changeLabel = match ? 'Cancel' : 'Add Now'
```

You were fixing the value of `windowMedia` (same as `isBrowser`) with a `const` and the state was trying to set a value of `undefined` at the time that the `window` was not set, you can simplify by setting the state only when the `window` is defined.

Answer (score -1):

You're doing it wrong. You're setting the const windowGlobal to be true/false and then use it in `useState(windowGlobal...)` which means windowGlobal is a bool and not a function. Use window directly like my example below:

```
const windowGlobal = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window
const [matches, setMatches] = useState(windowGlobal.matchMedia(query).matches)
```

Id go with making an if window is set, then execute the code.

```
const useMedia = (query) => {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(windowGlobal.matchMedia(query).matches)
  
  const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== 'undefined' && window;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isBrowser()) {
      const media = window.matchMedia(query)
      if (media.matches !== matches) setMatches(media.matches)
      const listener = () => setMatches(media.matches)
      media.addEventListener('change', listener)

      return () => media.removeEventListener('change', listener)
    }
  }, [matches, query])

  return matches
}
const match = useMedia('(max-width: 575px)')
const changeLabel = match ? 'Cancel' : 'Add Now'
```

Comment: which solution can you advice ?

Comment: @Bavarius I updated with an example on how I'd do it

Comment: when i run with `npm run` it's ok, but when i want build same error `WebpackError: TypeError: windowGlobal.matchMedia is not a function`

Comment: You need to use window instead of windowGlobal - which is an Bool in your code. I updated my example within useEffect. Use only window there